# how to add autocomplete for css in VS Code

Tags: css, editor, visual-studio-code

I don't have autocomplete for `!important` keyword in VS Code. File type is `CSS` and I don't have any plugins installed that would interfere with this autocomplete / IntelliSense.

[image]

How can this be added?

Answer (score 0):

Emmet works for me (it's embedded in vscode). Trigger character is `!` - exclamation mark.

[image]